# How to extract data from dynamically added layouts from items in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and can't make it work.**

I have a RecyclerView in my Android app where users can dynamically add items at runtime. Each item in the RecyclerView contains two EditTexts, and users input data into these fields.

Now, I need to retrieve the data entered by the user in these dynamically added items and perform further processing, such as saving it to a database.

project  https://github.com/giorgishubitidze3/fitnessApp

here is my adapter for the RV.

```
class CurrentSessionAdapter(viewModel: WorkoutViewModel, private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner): RecyclerView.Adapter<CurrentSessionAdapter.CurrentViewHolder>() {

    private var exercises: List<GymExercise> = emptyList()
    val viewModel = viewModel

    init {
//        viewModel.currentWorkouts.observe(lifecycleOwner) { newExercises ->
//            exercises = newExercises
//            notifyDataSetChanged()

            Log.d("observer2", "size of data: ${exercises.size}")
        Log.d("observer3", "data: ${exercises}")
//        }
    }


    //TODO destroy observer later

    inner class CurrentViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val tvTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.setTitle)
        val tvClass = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvClass2)
        val imageViewMuscle = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewMuscle2)
        val addBtn = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.addSetBtn)
        val setCounterLayout = itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.setCounterLayout)
        val editTextKG = itemView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etKG)
        val editTextREP = itemView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etREP)
        val checkBox = itemView.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.setCheckBox)
        val prev = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.previousSetTV)
        val removeBtn = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.removeSetBtn)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CurrentViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.current_session_rv_item, parent, false)
        return CurrentViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return exercises.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CurrentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentWorkout = exercises[position]

        holder.tvTitle?.text = currentWorkout.name ?: "Default Name"
        holder.prev?.text = currentWorkout.bodyPart ?: "Default Body Part"

        for(n in 1 until currentWorkout.setCount){
            val setCounterLayout = holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.verticalLinear)
            addSetCounterLayout(setCounterLayout)
        }

        holder.addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            // Add the logic to handle the button click and dynamically add setCounterLayout
            val setCounterLayout = holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.verticalLinear)
            addSetCounterLayout(setCounterLayout)
            viewModel.addSetCount(currentWorkout)
        }

        holder.removeBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val setCounterLayout = holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.verticalLinear)
            removeSetCounterLayout(setCounterLayout)
            viewModel.removeSetCount(currentWorkout)
        }


        fun uploadSetsToRoom(linearLayout: LinearLayout, dao: WorkoutDao){

            for(i in 0 until linearLayout.childCount){
                val dynamicLayout = linearLayout.getChildAt(i) as ViewGroup

                val checkBox = dynamicLayout.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.setCheckBox)
                val editTextWeight = dynamicLayout.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etKG)
                val editTextRep = dynamicLayout.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etREP)

                if (editTextWeight.text.isNotEmpty() && editTextRep.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val kgText = editTextWeight.text.toString()
                    val repText = editTextRep.text.toString()

                    val workout = Workout(currentWorkout.id.toInt(), currentWorkout.name, kgText, repText,
                        currentWorkout.setCount, 0)

                    viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
                        dao.insertWorkout(workout)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }







    private fun addSetCounterLayout(linearLayout: LinearLayout) {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(linearLayout.context)
        val setCounterLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_rv_item, linearLayout, false)
        linearLayout.addView(setCounterLayout)
    }

    private fun removeSetCounterLayout(linearLayout: LinearLayout) {
        val childCount = linearLayout.childCount
        if (childCount > 1) {
            linearLayout.removeViewAt(childCount - 1)
        }
    }

    fun clearData(){
        exercises= emptyList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    fun setData(newExercises: List<GymExercise>) {
        exercises = newExercises
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        Log.d("setData", "size of data: ${exercises.size}")
        Log.d("setData", "size of data: ${exercises}")
        Log.d("observer3", "data: ${exercises}")
    }




}
```

I inflate the layouts using addSetCounterLayout function
[exercise item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWvDz.jpg)

I need something to extract data from each item, workout names, reps, weights from the editTexts, etc.

**Is there any way to access dynamically added layouts inside RV items? or everything from each item.**